# Microsoft Graph Api gives Expired Device code today

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

I have been testing Microsoft Graph api user access token by following
[Java example URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java?tutorial-step=3) .
Yesterday it worked fine but today it always give me com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: ***Expired Device code*** . I dont' give any device code and tried it with created new registered app on [Azure Active Directory admin center](https://aad.portal.azure.com/)

```
    Consumer<DeviceCode> deviceCodeConsumer = (DeviceCode deviceCode) -> {
        System.out.println(deviceCode.message());
    };

    // Request a token, passing the requested permission scopes
    IAuthenticationResult result = app.acquireToken(
            DeviceCodeFlowParameters
                    .builder(scopeSet, deviceCodeConsumer)
                    .build()
    ).exceptionally(ex -> {
        System.out.println("Unable to authenticate - " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }).join();
```

Comment: Why do you say "I don't give any device code"? When you run this sample code project, the application displays a URL and device code like this "To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code F7CG945YZ to authenticate." Looks like the code you provided is expired.

Comment: Try to use an inprivate window to open the page.

Comment: That command line sentence used to come  before this error. I dont see that hereafter.

Comment: By the way  I was not giving device code but it was giving me device code right ?

Comment: Here is my code : https://github.com/yusufunlu/MicrosoftApiTrying

Comment: Yes. The device code is generated by the project and provided to you. Then you use it to authenticate. I can hardly tell what is wrong with your code. But you could download the completed project [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-java) and follow the [README](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-java/tree/master/demo) to run it.

Comment: I have tried what you gave github url and it gave me the below error. 
"GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
SdkVersion : graph-java/v1.6.0
Authorization : Bearer null"
I have tried different apps and new account with different azure account too

Comment: The access token is null. Please debug it to see what happened in "./graphtutorial/src/main/java/graphtutorial/Authentication.java" file:  `Authentication.initialize(appId); final String accessToken = Authentication.getUserAccessToken(appScopes);`

Comment: Thank you found the problem I access token problem was because of using object id instead of app.id . For some reasons I have created created new app and forgot to enable "Default client type" in Azure Active Directory

Comment: Glad to know this issue is resolved. To make this post treated as answered, I have moved the comment to the answer. You can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by an invalid device code request...which had `expiresIn=0`.

I found my error by debugging into `DeviceFlowRequest::acquireDeviceCode`. The `response` stated that "The provided client is not supported for this feature. The client application must be marked as 'mobile.'". (But this was masked by the try/catch which returned "Expired Device" error.)

This gave me the hint I needed on to update the application on https://aad.portal.azure.com/ - In Authentication, at the bottom (under advanced settings), I had neglected to check "Allow public client flows" - "Enable the following mobile and desktop flows", and click the save button (at the top).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the browser uses a Expired Device code in cookie.

The device code is generated by the project and provided to you. Then you use it to authenticate.

I didn't find if there is something wrong with your code.

A workaround is to download the completed project [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-java) and follow the [README](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-java/tree/master/demo) to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only thing I changed from the tutorial steps is selecting the 1st option in support account types. I was bale to solve this problem by selecting 2nd option (3rd option also will work I guess). But it is not currently supported by Microsoft identity platforms.[Refer here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/supported-accounts-validation)

Therefore I had only 2 options (1st and 2nd in below picture).

[image]